# Primes $p$ such that $3$ is a Primitive Root Modulo $p$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

In [this paper](http://homepages.math.uic.edu/~rfuller/primroot2.pdf) (Proposition 4) you can find statement :

> If $p$ is a prime of the form : $p = 2q + 1$ for some odd prime $q$,
>
> then $2$ is a primitive root modulo $p$ if and only if : $q \equiv 1, 5 \pmod 8$.

Is it true that :

> If $p$ is a prime of the form  : $p =3\cdot q \cdot (q+1)-1$ for some odd prime $q$,
>
> then $3$ is a primitive root modulo $p$ if and only if : $q \equiv 1, 5 \pmod {12}$.

[Legendre symbol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_symbol) for $3$ is :

$\left(\frac{3}{p} \right) =
\begin{cases}
 ~~~1, & \text{if } :p \equiv 1,11 \pmod {12} \\
 -1, & \text{if } : p \equiv 5,7 \pmod {12}
\end{cases}$

It is obvious that necessary condition is :  $q \equiv 1, 5 \pmod {12}$ since :

$3 \cdot(12t+7)^2+3(12t+7)-1 \equiv 11 \pmod {12}$

$3 \cdot(12t+11)^2+3(12t+11)-1 \equiv 11 \pmod {12}$

There is a theorem that states :

> $a$ is a primitive root modulo $~p~$ iff $~~ord_p(a) = \phi(p)$ .

So , how to prove that : $~~ord_p(3) =3\cdot q \cdot (q+1)-2 $ ?

**EDIT :**

Conjecture is false . Smallest counterexample is : $35862917$

Comment: A big reason, why the author was successful in deducing primitivity of 2 modulo $p$ is that he knows the prime factorization of $p-1=2q$, can test all the proper factors of $2q$, and exclude them as orders of $2$ modulo $p$. Do you know the factorization of $p-1=3q(q+1)-2$ in your case?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen,In this case number of factors isn't same for all $q$..

Comment: Don't you think that that makes the problem rather difficult? You have to show that $3^{(p-1)/r}$ is not congruent to $1\pmod p$ for all prime divisors $r$ of $p-1$.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen,I know that this isn't easy task...On the other hand I have checked statement for many primes of this form and haven't found any counterexample so it might be true...

Comment: Maybe you should tell us which primes you have checked, so we don't duplicate the work.

Comment: @GerryMyerson,Consecutive primes of the form $3\cdot q \cdot (q+1)-1$ , where : $q \equiv 1,5 \pmod {12}$ :$89 , 2609 , 4217 , 24029 , 28517 ,35969 , 67049 , 117017 , ....$